# why setTimeout in async function need to be wrapen again in new Pormise?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Why in need to use new Promise in async function?

I want to understand why my async/await Code is not working according to [async-await]: (https://javascript.info/async-await)

if I simply wrap a function in async , I get a Promise. 
like in the example:

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(alert); // 1
```

but when I wrap setTimeout code like this, it is not working:

```
let hello = await this.sleep_not_Working();
async sleep_not_Working()
    {
       setTimeout( ()=> {
            return "hello";
        }, 3000);
    }
```

I  know that this code will work, I just don't understand why???

```
let hello = await this.sleep_Work();
async sleep_Work()
    {
        return new Promise((resolve)=>( setTimeout(()=> {
            resolve("hello");
        }, 3000)));
    }
```

like in the example above, I've expected to get a promise, because I wrap it in async Header.

Hope to any Promises genuineness :)

Comment: `()=> {
            return "hello";
        }` does not notify that the task is completed. Hence, promise will not get updated status. Returning another promise does that. Hence it works.

Comment: @Rajesh can you explaine the difrences betwenn the example I've added:
https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: You have an `async` function and you tell code to wait using `await`. Now how does await know the processing is completed? Either if the body is executed completely, or you notify it like `async (done) => { ... fn body; done();}` You want to initiate a `setTimeout` which is a async task but your code will not wait as it will execute in global scope. In second example, you do `resolve(...)` which means you are specifically saying that the task is completed. Hence it works

Answer (score 2):

`async` is just sugar for returning a promise. So when you say

```
async sleep_not_Working()
{
   setTimeout( ()=> {
        return "hello";
    }, 3000);
}
```

That's basically the same as this:

```
function sleep_not_Working()
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            return "hello";
        }, 3000);
    })       
}
```

But that's not how promises work. Returning from an internal anonymous function doesn't resolve the promise, the only thing that resolves a promise is `resolve('hello')`

Answer (score 1):

An `async` function returns a Promise that resolves to the value that the `async` function returns.

In your code…

> ```
> async sleep_not_Working()
>     {
>        setTimeout( ()=> {
>             return "hello";
>         }, 3000);
>     }
> ```

`sleep_not_Working` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Only the arrow function you pass to `setTimeout` has a `return` statement, but that is a different function.

---

Note that it is pointless to use the `async` keyword on a function which returns an explicitly created function and which doesn't use `await` internally.